# How to use Distinct in middle or last column in query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005

I have a query like this :

```sql
 SELECT [LAMI], [LGMI], [GTIM], [SPED], [IGST], [XXXM] as deviceID,
        [PULSE_CTR], [FUEL_ADC]  
   FROM [Tracking] 
        INNER JOIN [Vehicles_Device_Rel] ON XXXM = '200039'
```

But I want like this:

```sql
 SELECT [LAMI], [LGMI], DISTINCT [GTIM], [SPED], [IGST],
        [XXXM] as deviceID, [PULSE_CTR], [FUEL_ADC]  
   FROM [Tracking] 
        INNER JOIN [Vehicles_Device_Rel] ON XXXM = '200039'
```

But I am getting an error :

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DISTINCT'.

Please help me i am new for sql server

Sample Data:

```
     LAMI     |     LGMI      |        GTIM             | SPED | IGST |  XXXM  | PULSE_CTR | FUEL_ADC |
--------------+---------------+-------------------------+------+------+--------+-----------+----------+
12.9215736389 | 77.5954818726 | 2014-05-21 08:51:00.000 |   0  |   1  | 200039 |    0.00   |     0    |
12.9215736389 | 77.5954818726 | 2014-05-21 18:51:00.000 |   0  |   1  | 200039 |    0.00   |     0    |
12.9215736389 | 77.5954818726 | 2014-05-25 03:51:00.000 |   0  |   1  | 200039 |    0.00   |     0    |
12.9215736389 | 77.5954818726 | 2014-05-25 03:51:00.000 |   0  |   1  | 200039 |    0.00   |     0    |
12.9215736389 | 77.5954818726 | 2014-05-25 14:35:00.000 |   1  |   1  | 200039 |    0.00   |     0    |
12.9215736389 | 77.5954818726 | 2014-05-25 14:35:00.000 |   0  |   1  | 200039 |    0.00   |     0    |
12.9215736389 | 77.5954818726 | 2014-05-25 14:35:00.000 |   0  |   1  | 200039 |    2.00   |     0    |
```

Comment: So as you want to show distinct GTIM, what should be the values of [LAMI],[LGMI] ?? Sum, Avg, First ?

Comment: You can't use `DISTINCT` for this. `DISTINCT` is for the entire set of columns. You will have to group by GTIM and use aggregation on the other columns. I'm assuming you're using MS Sql Server so check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx for help on how to do it.

Comment: LAMI is lattitude ,LGMI in longitude ,GTIM is DATETIME i want distinct datetime column and also i am using SQL server 2005

Comment: Can you post some sample data and your expected output?

Comment: 12.9215736389,77.5954818726,2014-05-21 8:51:00.000,0,1,200039,0.00,0
12.9215736389,77.5954818726,2014-05-21 8:51:00.000,0,1,200039,0.00,0
12.9215736389 77.5954818726 2014-05-21 18:51:00.000 0 1 200039 0.00 0
12.9164695740 77.5879440308 2014-05-25 03:14:00.000 0 1 200039 0.00 0
12.9164695740 77.5879440308 2014-05-25 03:14:00.000 0 1 200039 0.00 0

12.9164104462 77.5879516602 2014-05-25 14:35:00.000 0 1 200039 0.00 0
12.9164104462 77.5879516602 2014-05-25 14:35:00.000 0 1 200039 0.00 0
12.9164104462 77.5879516602 2014-05-25 14:35:00.000 0 1 200039 0.00 0

Comment: I want distinct using GTIM column

Comment: @user3647240: Answer Ksven's question. If you want GTIM to be distinct in your results, but there are two or more records for a GTIM in yor table, which LAMI etc. shall be shown for the GTIM? The greatest? The smallest? The avarage? Just a random match? And when GarethD asked for sample data and output, he was certainly looking for the same answer. (And we were expecting this in a readable form. You should have edited your question rather than posting a bulk of numbers in comments.)

Comment: in this i don't want any aggregate function just display distinct GTIM column

Comment: You want to show only GTIM? No LAMI, no LGMI, no SPED etc.? Then `SELECT DISTINCT GTIM FROM ...`and you are done. If, however, you want to show any of the other columns, you *must* decide which values to show. If you have two records GTIM 20140527 LAMI 1234 and GTIM 20140527 LAMI 5678 and you want to show just one record for GTIM 20140527, then which LAMI do you want to show with it, 1234 or 5678?

Answer (score 2):

I feel the need to explain the problem to you, rather than the solution as understanding the problem may assist you in solving the problem.

Imagine the following simple data set

```
+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
+------+------+------+
|  X   |   Y  |   4  |
|  X   |   Z  |   3  |
|  A   |   Y  |   1  |
|  A   |   Z  |   2  |
+------+------+------+
```

What you are essentially saying is that you want distinct values for one column, the problem is what values to choose from the other columns. So assuming we want only distinct values for Col1 (X and A) we will limit the results to 2 rows, but what rules should you apply to get values for col1 (Y or X) and col2 (1, 2, 3 or 4), i.e. you could take the first row for each, ordering by Col3:

```
+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
+------+------+------+
|  X   |   Z  |   3  |
|  A   |   Y  |   1  |
+------+------+------+
```

Or ordering By Col2:

```
+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
+------+------+------+
|  X   |   Y  |   4  |
|  A   |   Y  |   1  |
+------+------+------+
```

Or you could take the Max value of each of the other columns:

```
+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
+------+------+------+
|  X   |   Z  |   4  |
|  A   |   Z  |   2  |
+------+------+------+
```

The point is that **YOU** need to identify the logic you want to pick which value to choose, SQL Server (or any other DBMS for that matter) is unable to make this decision for you. Without this logic it is impossible to provide the answer to the question.

If all your other values are the same, so there is not really a choice to make then you can just use DISTINCT at the start of the query.

Answer (score 1):

use "distinct" at the beginning, it will remove duplicate rows and duplicated date.  As I see coordinates are the same for duplicated date

```
SELECT DISTINCT [LAMI], [LGMI], [GTIM], [SPED], [IGST],
    [XXXM] as deviceID, [PULSE_CTR], [FUEL_ADC]  
 FROM [Tracking] 
    INNER JOIN [Vehicles_Device_Rel] ON XXXM = '200039'
```

Comment: k But coordinates will change in same datetime that data i want to distinct

Comment: Please, post sample and result. The previous sample has tha same coordinates in one time.
If U have somthing like this 
12.9215736 77.5954818 2014-05-21 18:51:00.000
13.9215736 78.5954818 2014-05-21 18:51:00.000
What result should be?